# Determine if the sequence of functions converges.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This is a problem out of a book I am working on. I am asking if someone could verify my logic and help me correct mistakes. The question has 3 sub-categories I need to answer:

(i) is each $h_n(x)$ continuous at zero?

(ii) does $h_n(x) \rightarrow h(x)$ uniformily. (on $\mathbb{R}$).

(iii) is $h(x)$ continuous at $0$? (where $h(x)$ is the limit function.)

**Below is my attempt**

$h_n(x) = \begin{cases}
      1 & x = \frac{1}{n} \\
      x & x = \left\{1,\frac{1}{2},...,\frac{1}{n-1}\right\} \\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}
$

**(i)** $\textbf{Yes.}$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta = \frac{1}{n+1}$

Then $|x-0| < \delta$ implies $|h_n(x) - h_n(0)| = |0 - 0| = 0 < \epsilon$

**(ii)** $\textbf{No.}$ Observe first that

$h(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & x = 0 \\
      x & x = \left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\right\} \\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}$

Choose any $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\epsilon = 1$

(Example, Choose x = 0) Then $|h_N(x) - h(x)| \leq |0 - 1| = 1 \geq \epsilon$.

**(iii)** $\textbf{No.}$

Choose any $\delta > 0$ and let $\epsilon = 1$

Observe, by the Density of $\mathbb{I}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, I can find a $b \in \mathbb{I}$ satisfying $0 < b < \delta$.

Then $|x - 0| < \delta$ implies $|h(x) - h(0)| \leq |h(b) - h(0)| = |0 - 1| = 1 \geq \epsilon$

Comment: $h(0)$ must be zero since $h_n(0)=0$

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? If $n \rightarrow \infty$, then wouldn't the first part of $h(x)$ say $1$ if $x = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

observe that

$$(\forall n>0)\;\;\;\; h_n(\frac{1}{n})-h(\frac{1}{n})=1-\frac{1}{n}$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|h_n(x)-h(x)|\geq 1$$

the convergence is not uniform at $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Wouldn't $h(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{n}$ ?

Comment: I would like to try using definition of uniform convergence directly (if possible). In other words, show that there is no single N that works. I am not quite comfortable your notation on the last line even applies to the definition.

Comment: Wouldn't a counter example imply finding some x in the domain that makes the inequality false? My assumption is you are plugging in $x = 0$ ($n \rightarrow \infty$ implies $\frac{1}{n} = 0$). If that is the case, what would be the point for having the limit on the outside?

Comment: What would be the issue with choosing $x = 0$ or just choosing $x = \frac{1}{n+1}$? I am really not seeing why $x = \frac{1}{n}$ has to be the choice. Sure, if $n > 1$, then choosing $x = \frac{1}{n}$ when $\epsilon = .5$ works, but where did my choosing of $x=0$ go wrong?